# How to read a dataframe of encoded strings from csv in python

Tags: python, utf-8, pandas

Suppose I read an html website and I get a list of names, such as: 'Amiel, Henri-Frédéric'.

In order to get the list of names I decode the html using the following code:

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://xxx.htm")
html = f.read()
html=html.decode('utf8')
t.feed(html)
t.close()
lista=t.data
```

At this point, the variable lista contains a list of names like:

[u'Abatantuono, Diego',
... ,
u'Amiel, Henri-Frédéric']

Now I would like to:

1. put these names inside a DataFrame;
2. save the DataFrame in a csv file;
3. read the csv in Python through a DataFrame

For simplicity, let's take in consideration just the above name to complete steps 1 to 3. I would use the following code:

```
name=u'Amiel, Henri-Fr\xe9d\xe9ric'
name=name.encode('utf8')
array=[name]
df=pd.DataFrame({'Names':array})
df.to_csv('names')
uni=pd.read_csv('names')
uni #trying to read the csv file in a DataFrame
```

At this point i get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 67: invalid continuation byte
```

If I substitute the last row of the above code with:

```
print uni
```

I can read the DataFrame but I don't think it is the right way to handle this issue.

I red many questions posted by other users about this argument but I didn't get to solve this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both`to_csv` method and `read_csv` function take an `encoding` argument. Use it. And work with unicode internally. If you don't, trying to encode/decode inside your program *will get you*.

```
import pandas as pd

name = u'Amiel, Henri-Fr\xe9d\xe9ric'
array = [name]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':array})
df.to_csv('names', encoding='utf-8')
uni = pd.read_csv('names', index_col = [0], encoding='utf-8')
print uni  # for me it works with or without print
```

out:

```
                   Names
0  Amiel, Henri-Frédéric
```

Comment: Sorry, your code works but only if you use 'print uni' as the last row of code. If you try to use just 'uni' you get the error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 67: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: @fabrizio_ff--what `pandas`/`numpy` version are you using?

Comment: @root-- numpy: 1.6.2 // pandas: 0.9.1. I tried to use your last code but if I write just 'uni' I'll get the same error (instead it works with 'print uni').

Comment: @fabrizio_ff -- try to upgrade `pandas` to the latest version and see if you still get the error.

Comment: @root--upgraded pandas to 0.10.1. If I use the IPython Notebook I get the same error while if I use the spyder console it works. Maybe the error was due to the fact that I was using the iPython Notebook? Thank you!

Comment: @fabrizio_ff -- I actually tested it with `IPython 0.13.1`, what version are you on?

Comment: I also have the 0.13.1 version.